# ionic open accordion by default from controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have implemented ionic accordion effect using the following code. It was working fine as expected, but i want to open the first accordion by default.

```
    <ion-item class="item-stable"
              ng-click="toggleGroup(0)"
              ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(0)}">
              <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(0) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
                    &nbsp;
                        Permanant Address
    </ion-item>

    <div class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(0)">
         ---------
    </div>

<ion-item class="item-stable"
              ng-click="toggleGroup(1)"
              ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(1)}">
              <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(1) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
                    &nbsp;
                        Temporary Address
    </ion-item>

    <div class="item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(1)">
         ---------
    </div>
```

### controller

```
 $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };
```

Comment: can't you set $scope.shownGroup equal to 0 to do that?

Comment: I tried to calling $scope.toggleGroup(0); in controller but not working

Comment: best to set up a codepen

Comment: I have got the code from this source http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this line at the end of the for loop:

```
  $scope.shownGroup = $scope.groups[0];
```